# Oauth Consent Screen Form

Tags: oauth-2.0, verification

I implemented an Android App that integrates with Google Drive API. It basic app that shows GDrive folders and files and allows the user to upload new files and create directories.

I am not accesing other domains other than those of Google (I only access Google Drive API after authenticating)

I don't manage to fill the OAuth credentials consent screen to submit it for verification.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgXYh.png)
- In Authorized Domains I write google.com
- In Application Homepage link and in Application Privacy Policy link I can not write URLs that sit under google.com (for example: https://sites.google.com/view/xxx). I get this error: "Invalid domain: URL must be hosted on a domain listed in the "Authorized domains" section. "

Comment: did you get out of this situation ? If so , how ???